# Отличие перегрузки метода onCreate при изменении ориентации и при изменении РАЗМЕРА шрифта в настройках телефона

Tags: android

Код в студии!:

```
 public class Task_list extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{
SharedPreferences sPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor ed;
ListView li;
DB db;
Cursor cursor;
SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;
int task_sort, archive, report, task_report;
long task_id;
ImageView icon_unsort, icon_sortAZ, icon_sortZA, icon_home, icon_help;
Intent intent;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_list);

    //получаем данные из файла "Pref"
    sPref = getSharedPreferences("Pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    ed = sPref.edit();

    task_sort = sPref.getInt("task_sort", 1);

    // объявляем и отождествляем переменные с элементами
    icon_home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon_home);
    icon_unsort  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon_unsort);
    icon_sortAZ  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon_sortAZ);
    icon_sortZA  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon_sortZA);
    icon_help  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon_help);

    // открываем подключение к БД
    db = new DB(this);
    db.open();
    // переменные для адаптера
    scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view, null,
            new String[]{"name", "archive"}, new int[]{R.id.textView_task, R.id.LinearLayout_task}, 0);
    // указываем адаптеру свой биндер
    scAdapter.setViewBinder(new ArchiveViewBinder());
    // создааем список
    li = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.li);
    //настраиваем список (соединяем с адаптером)
    li.setAdapter(scAdapter);

    // создаем лоадер для чтения данных
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(5, null, this);

    intent = getIntent();
    final int task_from = intent.getIntExtra("from", 0);
    //реакция на выбор пункта (короткое нажатие)
       li.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
       {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id)
        {
            cursor = scAdapter.getCursor();
            task_id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            task_report = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("report"));

            if (task_from == 1) // выбирает задачу для отчета
            {
                String task_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                int task_archive = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("archive"));
                intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("task_id", task_id);
                intent.putExtra("task_archive", task_archive);
                intent.putExtra("task_report", task_report);
                intent.putExtra("task_name", task_name);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                Task_list.this.finish();
            }
            if (task_from == 2) // работает как формирование выбранных задач
            {
                db.report_change(task_id, task_report);
                getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(5).forceLoad();
            }
            if (task_from == 3) // выбирает задачу для отчета 2
            {
                String task_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                int task_archive = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("archive"));
                intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("task_id", task_id);
                intent.putExtra("task_archive", task_archive);
                intent.putExtra("task_report", task_report);
                intent.putExtra("task_name", task_name);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                Task_list.this.finish();
            }
        }
    });

}

public void onclick_icon_unsort (View view)
{
    task_sort = 1;
    ed.putInt("task_sort", task_sort);
    ed.commit();
    getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(5).forceLoad();
}

public void onclick_icon_sortAZ (View view)
{
    task_sort = 2;
    ed.putInt("task_sort", task_sort);
    ed.commit();
    getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(5).forceLoad();
}

public void onclick_icon_sortZA (View view)
{
    task_sort = 3;
    ed.putInt("task_sort", task_sort);
    ed.commit();
    getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(5).forceLoad();
}

public void onclick_icon_home (View view)
{
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    this.finish();
}

public void onclick_icon_help (View view)
{
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Help_Task_list.class));

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    intent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
    finish();
}

protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    // закрываем курсор и подключение при выходе
    cursor = scAdapter.getCursor();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bndl) {
    return new MyCursorLoader(this, db);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor)
{
    scAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    // обновляем состояние кнопок
    switch (task_sort)
    {
    case 1:
        icon_unsort.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_sort_grey600_36dp) ;
        icon_sortAZ.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_sort_ascending_white_36dp) ;
        icon_sortZA.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_sort_descending_white_36dp) ;
        break;
    case 2:
        icon_unsort.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_sort_white_36dp) ;
        icon_sortAZ.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_sort_ascending_grey600_36dp) ;
        icon_sortZA.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_sort_descending_white_36dp) ;
        break;
    case 3:
        icon_unsort.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_sort_white_36dp) ;
        icon_sortAZ.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_sort_ascending_white_36dp) ;
        icon_sortZA.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_sort_descending_grey600_36dp) ;
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader)
{
}

class ArchiveViewBinder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder
{
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex)
    {
        archive = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("archive"));
        report = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("report"));

        switch (view.getId())
        {
            // меняем фон линейной разметки в случае архивной задачи
            case R.id.LinearLayout_task:
                if (archive == 1 && report == 1) view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_change_task);
                if (archive == 1 && report == 0) view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_stop);
                if (archive == 0 && report == 1) view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_start);
                if (archive == 0 && report == 0) view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_task);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader
{
    DB db;
    public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DB db)
    {
        super(context);
        this.db = db;
    }
    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground()
    {
        Cursor cursor = db.list_task_report();
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

}

При переворачивании экрана вызывается повторно метод onCreate, что приводит к краху приложения. Если запретить это путем указания в манифесте

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Task_list"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

приложение не умирает при переворачивании экрана за счет "обещания" самостоятельно обработать смену ориентации:

```
 android:configChanges="orientation"
```

При этом оно так же хорошо переживает и смену размера шрифта в настройках телефона, и изменяет размер шрифта внутри приложения в соответствии с выбранными настройками, хотя широкого "обещания" нет, наподобие этого:

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|fontScale"
```

Возникает вопрос: почему перезагрузка в связи со сменой ориентации приводит к краху, а перезагрузка в связи со сменой размера шрифта - нет?
Практическое значение этого вопроса заключается в том, что другое приложение, использующее аналогичный код (значимую разницу в коде я не смог найти, как не пытался), уже умирает при изменении размера шрифта в настройках телефона. В чем особенность перегрузки приложения в связи с изменениями размера шрифта?

Comment: почему не можете посмотреть лог? так можно только гадать, при изменении шрифта происходит изменение конфигурации после чего возможно возникает какой то NullPointerException. Нужны логи!

Comment: @St-st Покажите код, иначе возможно вопрос закроют.

Comment: Ну так найдите, как посмотреть лог, выжпрограммист!

Comment: код самый обыкновенный: стрингс да ЛистВью.

Comment: посмотреть лог не могу, код самый простой .. с такими вводными вам нужно обращаться на форум экстрасенсов, здесь вам вряд ли помогут.

Answer (score 4):

Ничего удивительного: Android поддерживает не все шрифты. В зависимости от версии, поддерживаются или только True Type или True Type и Open Type шрифты.

Ну а уж если вы решили воткнуть какой-нибудь растровый шрифт, то тогда, как говорится *шерифа не волнуют проблемы индейцев* :)

P.S. Не может такого быть, что нельзя посмотреть логи. Взять проводок и воткнуть его в комп? Или установить на девайсе [CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=en) - неужели все так запущено?

Comment: шрифт стандартный, ничего не менял. Сейчас установлю CatLog. Подскажите где там искать нужный лог?

Comment: Рут прав нет, к сожалению.